# Music player with Nested Playlist

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there an MP3 player / manager that supports nested playlists?

For example, for Iron Maiden I would have:

Iron Maiden
|- Long Songs
|- Short Songs

So playing "Iron Maiden" would play both "Long Songs" and "Short Songs" playlists, but I would still be able to choose just "Short Songs".

Comment: there is an open issue in Clementine requesting nested playlists: http://code.google.com/p/clementine-player/issues/detail?id=2994

Answer (score 0):

Whilst a slightly different approach, [Quod Libet](http://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/) has supported features like this for a while now (I am one of the devs).  Using its slightly mind-bending [search syntax](http://quodlibet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/searching.html):

```
~playlists="Iron Maiden"
```

...would return everything in an *Iron Maiden* playlist, but:

```
~playlists=|(Long Songs, Short Songs, Party Favourites)
```

...would return everything in any of those, and:

```
&(artist=Iron Maiden,~playlists="Long Songs")
```

...would return everything *by* Iron Maiden featuring in the *Long Songs* playlist, but you could do this automatically by:

```
&(artist=Iron Maiden, #(length > 300))
```

...which returns all songs by Iron Maiden over 5 minutes (300 seconds) long. Magic!

Answer (score 0):

[Banshee](http://banshee.fm/) supports nested playlists, including nested smart / dynamic playlists. Unfortunately it is not longer actively maintained. Banshee also supports limiting how many songs are chosen. So you can, for example, have one dynamic playlist that chooses 50 songs of a certain type and another than chooses 200 of another, and the make a playlist that combines them, giving you a 4:1 mix of the two types of songs.

Quod Libet allows allows the search syntax to reference playlists, but you can't reference other searches. Therefore nested *smart* playlists are not supported, as far as I can tell.

Clementine has not yet implemented nested playlists, unfortunately. They have moved their issue tracking to GitHub. See https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine/issues/1968

Comment: Well, I can no longer download banshee. Quod Libet is a "no" and so is clementine. Bummer the answer to this question is "no" :(